# jQgrid colum filtering is not working in single column

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

jQgrid table is workin fine. In the last line I've enabled column filtering. Search/Filtering in other column is working fine. But not working on the the `Status` column that has been generated from `formatter`

```
$('#jqGrid').jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data    : res.data,
    colModel: [
        {
            label : 'Batch No.', name:'batch_no', firstsortorder:'asc'
        },
        {
            label : 'Batch Wt.', name:'expected_batch_wt', formatter:'number', align:'right'
        }
        ,
        // ... 
        // ...

        {
            label : 'Status'
            ,formatter:function (cellvalue, options, rowObject){
                if(condition)
                    status = 'MSG 1';
                else if(condition)
                    status = 'MSG 2';
                else
                    status = 'DEF MSG';
                return status;
            }
            ,align : 'center'
            // ,sortable : false
        }
    ],
    rowNum              : 1000,
    rownumbers          : true,
    pager               : '#jqGridPager',
    caption             : `CURRENT STOCK REPORT`,
    height              : '500px',
    width               : '1500',
    footerrow           : true,
        userDataOnFooter    : true,
    gridComplete        : function(){
        var $grid               = $('#jqGrid'),
            sum_batch_count     = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'batch_no', false, 'count'),
            sum_batch_wt        = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'expected_batch_wt', false, 'sum');
        $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { 
            'batch_no'              : sum_batch_count,
            'expected_batch_wt'     : sum_batch_wt
        });
    }
});

jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
```

Comment: What is the error reported? Do you see any error message in the console? There are two variables in the formatter, which seems  that they are defined outside the grid  - maybe the problem is here. To testif there is a problem in the formatter you can simple ignore it and test.

Comment: no error in console

Answer (score 0):

In your case datatype is local and the formatter shows certain value depending on condition. This value is not connected with your actual local data. When a datatype is local the search is performed within local data array - in your case this is: **res.data**. Since this data does not contain your new constructed values, the search return nothing.

To solve the problem one possible solution is to use unformatter function.

Depending on the jqGrid version used (Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrtid, jqGrid <= 4.7) you have diffrent options, but is needed to know the version. I recommend you too to search this site  for solving the problem you have.